# Проблемы с работой в PHPExcel через крон

Tags: php, cron, phpexcel

```
$current_file = DOCROOT.'/upload/export/'.$id.'.xlsx';
if (file_exists($current_file)) {
  unlink($current_file);
}
copy(DOCROOT.  '/upload/export/0.xlsx', $current_file);


//крафт дока и заполнение названиями столбцов
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2 - > load($current_file);
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2 - > load($current_file); // Empty Sheet
$excel2 - > setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excel2 - > getActiveSheet() 
        - > SetCellValue('a1', 'Уникальный идентификационный номер карты') 
        - > SetCellValue('b1', 'Баланс') 
        - > SetCellValue('c1', 'До какой даты действительна') 
        - > SetCellValue('d1', 'ФИО') 
        - > SetCellValue('e1', 'Пол') 
        - > SetCellValue('f1', 'Телефон') 
        - > SetCellValue('g1', 'Email') 
        - > SetCellValue('h1', 'send_sms') 
        - > SetCellValue('i1', 'send_email') 
        - > SetCellValue('j1', 'Дата рождения') 
        - > SetCellValue('k1', 'Активна') 
        - > SetCellValue('l1', 'Блокирована') 
        - > SetCellValue('m1', 'Выдана'); /**/
//Заполняем таблицу
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
```

Документ копируется,все хорошо,но вот на этой строчке скрипт падает `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');`

если в браузере запустить-нормально все.В чем проблема?о_О

Обычный текстовый файл в подобной обработке пишет спокойно.

З.Ы,

Если запускать через консоль-все работает....

Comment: Возможно памяти не хватает?

Comment: @lampa,в посте весь скрипт который выполняется-я уже его полностью урезал.прикол в том что в браузере выполняется прекрасно.и эта и полная где еще запрос на выборку и доп.записи в этот  файл.

Comment: что значит падает? ошибка-то какая?

Comment: @Etki,если запустить через панельку(выполнить сейчас) завершается 137.а если запустить из консоли-все прекрасно проходит.поставил на выполнение-тоже не выолняется

Comment: Выводит-то он что? Сделайте перенаправление в файл через `> /tmp/out.log`, наверняка там более детальная ошибка. И да, судя по тому, что через консоль он выоплняется - дело в настройке окружения cron.

Comment: @Etki,я перенаправлял лог-он пустой вообще.вчера начало работать(причем вместе с запись данных из выборки)-начал чистить код от комментов-перестало работать.начал возвращать обратно удаленное-не работает.вообще фигня какая-то.и да,он по какой-то причине может создать writer.

Comment: @Etki,как задрала эта магия крона,которая то работает,то не работает.все сегодня прекрасно работает....

Comment: @DarkVss как и в случае с 99% остальной "магии" в программировании, проблема в неправильной готовке. У крона свой собственный environment, поэтому там нужно в два раза внимательней следить за абсолютными путями и $PATH.

Comment: @Etki,значит это из 1%-ибо ничерта не менялось)))даже сервак не перезагружали.

Comment: Да верьте во что хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищите ошибку в логах. Варианты проблем:

- память
- права доступа (cli и web версии работают от разных аккаунтов)
- ограничение open_basedir
- текущая директория не та, что вы думаете (!!!)

Comment: 1)с правами все нормально;2)именно та что я думаю;3)я тять специально выделил на какой строчке падает.причем тут 2-4?. Как бороться с возможным недостатком памяти?

Comment: А вы точно знаете что происходит в том методе? Почему исключили №3? Про текущую директорию в CLI тоже не так очевидно, как некоторые думают. А вы в курсе? Память это самая  маловероятная причина я считаю. А заглянуть в логи вы просто обязаны.

Comment: как я уже написал-лог пуст.и проблема именно в createWriter(). насколько мне известно-опен не включен.

Comment: На всякий случай вот вам ссылки: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel , http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Answer (score 2):

Проблема может быть в правах доступа. Когда вы обращаетесь к скрипту из-под вебсервера, то юзером будет apache (или www-data, и т.д). Когда запускаете из крона, то пользователь соответственно тот, чей кронтаб вы редактировали.
Приведите полный лог ошибки.

Comment: запускаю из под рута.в этом же файле(где лежит эта функция) несколько скриптов дополнительно. в var/log/sуslog пусто. при запуске из панели выдает 137

Comment: syslog не при чем.
 Включите ошибки
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Выполняйте как
`php your_script.php > /tmp/errors 2>&1`